# How to access typedefs from inherited template

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I have following code snippet:

```
template <typename T>
struct ChildStruct
{
  typedef std::map<int,T> Tmap;
};

struct DataStruct: public ChildStruct<long>
{

};

void Test()
{
  DataStruct::ChildStruct<long>::Tmap map;
}
```

It's possible to access a Tmap typedef located in the ChildStruct from outside of DataStruct without typedef-ing this ChildStruct inside of Datastruct?

When I use mentioned code snippet in Visual Studio, everything works OK, but linux/macos g++ give me error:

```
error: 'ChildStruct' is not a member of 'DataStruct'
```

I found a way by defining a helper typedef inside od DataStruct:

```
struct DataStruct: public ChildStruct<long>
{
    typedef ChildStruct<long> ChildStructLong;
};

void Test()
{
    DataStruct::ChildStructLong::Tmap map;
}
```

But I would preffer a way without *ChildStructLong* definition.

Thanks!

**Edited:**

The solution is call ChildStruct directly from outside of DataStruct as suggest Christian Rau. Sometime the simplest solution is the best solution ;-)

Comment: Why not just use `ChildStruct<long>::Tmap` (without the preceding `DataStruct`)?

Comment: You're right ;-). I didn't realize that it can be accomplished by this way. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
typename Foo<double>::my_typedef blah;
```

Comment: `typename` seems to be the answer to most templating issues :P

Comment: When I try to use following defintion: void Test() { typename DataStruct::ChildStruct<long>::Tmap map; } compiler give me this error: error C2899: typename cannot be used outside a template declaration

Comment: Why do you need the typename here? The nested typedef isn't dependent on any template parameter

Comment: @Xeo See the part of the question: "It's possible to access a Tmap typedef located in the ChildStruct from outside of DataStruct without typedef-ing this ChildStruct inside of Datastruct?"  It's true, he shouldn't need anything while inside the object but outside of it...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `DataStruct::Tmap` directly?

```
#include <map>

template <typename T>
struct A
{
  typedef std::map<int, T> map_type;
};

struct B : A<int>
{ };

int main()
{
  B::map_type x;
}
```

See it working [here](http://ideone.com/3mtOV).

Comment: Because in my real application struct B is defined like : A<Object_One>,A<Object_two>,... so I need to specify which of type I need. But the answer is to use directly A<Object_one> without B::. I didn't realize this simply solution.

Comment: Oh well, you could have mentioned it :) Just one thing: the first code snippet in your question works fine with gcc 4.5.0 and beyond (tested with 4.6 and 4.7).

Comment: thanks for note. I checked my versions and it's 4.4.5 on Linux and 4.2.1 on MacOs. I will try to update them.